# Intellij gradle - using explicit module groups VS using qualified names

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I am trying to create a Gradle Java application.

In the New Project wizard, two options are available:

- using explicit module groups
- using qualified names

What do those two options mean? What are the differences?

Comment: Please take a look at this article for some tips: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/09/intellij-idea-2017-3-eap-grouping-modules-according-to-their-qualified-names-and-more/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- using explicit module groups

This refers to the ability to manually create groups of modules using whatever naming you like, and assigning modules to whichever groups you like.  You can manipulate your module groups in Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Modules.  This functionality has been in Intellij for some time.  This doesn't affect the behavior of your code, but is simply a way for you to stay organized.

- using qualified names

This is a newer option.  It refers to the qualified module names introduced by Java 9 Jigsaw, which formalized the concept of modules in Java.  If you choose this option, your modules will be grouped by their Jigsaw module names.  In other words, Intellij will visually organize your modules according to the way Java understands them to be grouped.

Comment: Be aware this functionality (grouping in IJ in general) is quite buggy. In my case it flattens the whole structure every time I update one of my build.grade files.